# Service returning undefined to the controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This is my service:

```
'use strict';

    app
    .service('myService', function($http) {

        this.getJSON = function() {
            return $http.get('someUrl/dataForm').then(function(data){
                return data.result;
            });
        };
    });
```

And in my controller I have:

```
'use strict'
        app.controller('myController', function ($scope, myService) {

            myService.getJSON().then(function(data){
                $scope.myData =data;
            });
            console.log($scope.myData);
        });
```

I can see that the http call is successfully returning a JSON value but the console log shows that the value of myData is undefined.
What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Place the console.log inside

```
 myService.getJSON().then(function(data){
                $scope.myData =data;
                console.log($scope.myData);
 });
```

[**DEMO**](https://plnkr.co/edit/wl917ZYVDQWUmyXqVNdT?p=preview)

Comment: It still seems to be displaying undefined. After inspection in Chrome i can see that it's making a call and getting the JSON. not sure why the console is displaying undefined.

Comment: @shanwar check the demo

Comment: my data was being returned as a list not a map so data.result was not working. I changed the api request to send a map and now it works fine ! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Update the code in the controller

```
'use strict';
app.service('myService', function($http) {
    this.getJSON = function() {
     return $http.get('someUrl/dataForm').then(function(data){
            return data.result;
        });
    };
});
```

controller

```
  'use strict'
   app.controller('myController', function ($scope, myService) {
        myService.getJSON().then(function(data){
            $scope.myData =data;
           console.log($scope.myData);
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the code of your controller:

```
'use strict'
    app.controller('myController', function ($scope, myService) {

        myService.getJSON().then(function(data){
            $scope.myData =data;
            console.log($scope.myData);
        });

    });
```

This happen because getJSON is an asycronous method, the request to getJSON method not provoke that javascript wait to response, adding console.log in ".then" will solve your issue.

By the way, with getJSON you are working with a concept named "promises", i let you a link explanatory about that with $http

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

Answer (score 1):

1. $http.get() returns promise object.
2. promise object has then(), catch(), finally() methods.
3. then is called when success, catch when error.

   change your service to,

```js
app.service('myService', function($http) {
  this.getJSON = function() {
    return $http.get('someUrl/dataForm'); //returns promise object
  };
});
```

and controller to,

```js
app.controller('myController', function($scope, myService) {
  var promise = myService.getJSON();
  //after resolving then method get called
  promise.then(function(data) {
    $scope.myData = data;
    console.log($scope.myData);
  });
});
```